# Remove Square Brackets and keep text depending on context

Tags: php

I have a string as so:

```
[[EARTH]] [[Machine]] [[Monster Card|monsters]]
If this card is [[Link Summon]]ed: You can [[Add a card|add]] 1 "[[Ancient Gear]]" monster or 1 "[[Geartown]]" from your [[Main Deck|Deck]] to your [[hand]]. You can [[target]] 1 [[Spell Card|Spell]]/[[Trap Card|Trap]] you [[control]] and 1 [[face-up]] monster your opponent controls; [[destroy]] that card you control, and if you do, change that opponents monsters [[ATK]]/[[DEF]] to 0 until the end of this [[turn]]. You can only use each [[effect]] of "Ancient Gear Ballista" [[once per turn]].
```

I'm using the following piece of code to remove all square brackets:

```
$stringout = str_replace(array('[[',']]'),'',$stringout);
```

However, when the brackets contain `|` character, I need to keep only the text after this character.

So from this:

```
[[Monster Card|monsters]]
```

To this:

```
monsters
```

I tried this:

```
$stringout = str_replace(array('[[|',']]'),'',$stringout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really more a job for preg_replace and regular expressions, than simple string replacement.

```
$result = preg_replace('#\[\[(?:[^\]]*\|)?([^\]]*)\]\]#', '$1', $input);
```

`(?:[^\]]*\|)?` is a non-capturing group, that allows for an *optional* `...|` part. Optional, so that `$1` will always refer to the second part, which would either be the rest *after* that, or the full content between `[[…]]`, if there was no `|`.

Comment: This does the job! Although I would be lying if I said it doesn't confuse me. I think I need to read up on my preg_replace and learn it a bit better. I was trying to avoid it due to this confusion but since it works well, it's best to learn it. Thank you!